# How to use result of socket.on in socket.emit?

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io

I want to know how two use the result of socket.on in the server and send that result to the client side with socket.emit.

[image: Socket code]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  To post a question about code here, you must include the code in your question, pasted as text and formatted appropriately as code.  This is a requirement on this site.  Please use the "edit" link to fix your question.

Comment: Also, please make sure your question is completely clear and you describe what problem you ran into when you tried your code, what debugging steps you took and what you learned from those debugging steps.

Comment: Also, when you post here, please check back several times in the first 30 minutes after posting so if your question is unclear and people are asking questions, you can clarify it.  That will prevent your question from getting downvotes, may prevent it from getting closed for not following the rules and will maximize your chance that you can engage someone to answer it since questions generally get seen by the most people within the first hour and they need to be clear questions without any confusion in that time period.

Comment: @cabrerahector - Your edit is not appropriate.  Code should be pasted into questions as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.on('socketName',function(params) {
    console.log(params);

    //your another codes

    socket.emit('another socket', {somData: "sample data"});
});
```

above codes will run aftrer emitting

```
socketName
```

from client and params is inputs from client. then with

```
socket.emit('another socket', {somData: "sample data"});
```

you can emit another socket for client to pass any data like someData to client.
with above code in your server, you can get data from client and send data to that.